# Bootstrap modal doesnt works in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal with remote content via `href` which is working fine on the desktop by including `menu.php` and not working in mobile by including `menu.php` but if i put the contents of `menu.php` direct in the main file `index.php` it works fine else it opens `restAdmin_add_cuisines.php` in the browser.

What is the problem in that?

**Link**

```
<li><a href="restAdmin_add_cuisines.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Cuisine</a></li>
```

**Modal**

```
<div style="z-index: 99999;" class="modal fade" id="addAdmin" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**menu.php**

```
<nav class="navigation text-right" data-menu-type="1200">
<ul class="nav text-uppercase">
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Adding Records</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">                     
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_cuisines.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Cuisine</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_restaurants.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Restaurant</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_offer.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Offer</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_menu_items.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Menu Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_choiceItemNo.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Choice Item No</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_choiceItems.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Choice Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_mainArea.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Main Area</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_subArea.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Sub Area</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_coupon.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Coupon</a></li>
    <li><a href="restAdmin_add_cardtype.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addAdmin">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Card Type</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How are you applying the contents of menu.php to the modal? with jquery? Can you add menu.php to your question as well.

Comment: @CesarBielich please check i have added `menu.php`

Comment: your php file looks like html, let me see php code

Comment: @CesarBielich this is the codewhat i have entered in the php file.

Comment: if you're passing straight html why the need to include it? Why don't you just hardcode it in the page like you said and it works.

Comment: @CesarBielich just to keep the page clean